# Testing the endpoints of the interval of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the interval of convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^k +3)^k(x-1)^k$

I know that this is a power series with $x_0$=1. So we are able to find R with the equation R= $\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}|a_k|^\frac{1}{k}}$. We also know that $a_k$ is ((-1)^k +3)^k. This yields that R=$\frac{1}{4}$. So our interval of convergence is given as ($\frac{3}{4}$,$\frac{5}{4}$). When testing the endpoints we know that the root and ratio tests won't work, and we can't use a comparison test, but what test can we use to check the endpoints.

I am just struggling on figuring out what test to use and how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x = 3/4$, the general summand is \begin{align*}
& \phantom{={}} ((-1)^k + 3)^k (-1/4)^k  \\
&= ((-1)^k(-1/4) + 3(-1/4))^k  \\
&= ((-1)^{k+1}/4 + -3/4)^k  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which alternates between $(-1)^k$ and $(-1/2)^k$.  In particular, when $k$ is even, the general summand is $(-1)^k$, which does not decrease to zero, so the sum does not converge.

When $x = 5/4$, the general summand is
\begin{align*}
& \phantom{={}} ((-1)^k + 3)^k (1/4)^k  \\
&= ((-1)^k(1/4) + 3(1/4))^k  \\
&= ((-1)^k/4 + 3/4)^k  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which is $1^k$ when $k$ is even, so again the terms do not go to zero, so the sum does not converge.

(This [$n^\text{th}$ term test for divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) is frequently effective at the endpoints of a power series.  Although we *can* find series which are not resolved by it.)

Comment: why don't you consider the case where n is odd, won't that make this argument fall apart?

Comment: @Logan : What is the limit of a sequence that is alternately $1$ and $0$?  If the sequence converges to zero, all subsequences converge to zero, including the subsequence with $k$ odd.  If any subsequence does not converge to zero, the sequence does not.